# Fill sessionRegistry and session control

Tags: spring, security, model-view-controller

Good evening to everyone.
I'm trying to set up a simple MVC site without using xml configurations but only java code.
The site has public and private contents and is managed with spring security.
I don't want to have cookies so I wrote

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Set<SessionTrackingMode> getSessionTrackingModes() {
        return EnumSet.of(SessionTrackingMode.SSL);
    }
}
```

When I configure the MVC I define the beans

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.csbab.spring")
public class SpringWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "sessionRegistry")
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
      return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name = "httpSessionEventPublisher")
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
```

In the security class I have

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
        ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry authorizeRequests = http.authorizeRequests();

        authorizeRequests.and()
          .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(1) // How many session the same user can have? This can be any number you pick
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry);
    ...
```

When the user log in this code is called

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

If I try to access an

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
```

is always empty (even if the the user is logged and the ssl session seems active) and the security check of number of session fails...

Any suggestions?

thanks.

going on (noone has replied in the while...)
I added

```
@Bean(name = "sessionAuthenticationStrategy")
public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy(){
    List<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> delegateStrategies=new ArrayList<SessionAuthenticationStrategy>();
    ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrent = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry);
    concurrent.setMaximumSessions(1);
    concurrent.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(true);
    delegateStrategies.add(concurrent);
    delegateStrategies.add(new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy());
    delegateStrategies.add(new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry));
    return new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(delegateStrategies);
}
```

I removed

authorizeRequests.and()
          .sessionManagement()...

and I changed the login code to

```
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authentication, request, response);
            return determineTargetUrl(authentication);
```

the sessionRegistry has started :) and i made first positive test opening explorer and chrome (the second login is refused)

but when I tried to login from a new window inside chrome (or another instance of chrome) I'm able to make two cuncurrent login (sharing the same session) and I have this message in the log:

Your servlet container did not change the session ID when a new session was created. You will not be adequately protected against session-fixation attacks

any idea?

nosce te ipsum...it is only code...
To do what I want in my scenario (that maybe is not usual) I have to do something different...
Reading the code I realized I'm not interested at all in session fixation, I want a single session per user, If another session is requested it's a security problem or an error...so I wrote...

```
@Bean(name = "sessionAuthenticationStrategy")
public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy(){
    List<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> delegateStrategies=new ArrayList<SessionAuthenticationStrategy>();
    ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrent = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry);
    concurrent.setMaximumSessions(1);
    concurrent.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(true);
    delegateStrategies.add(concurrent);
    delegateStrategies.add(new SessionSingleUseProtectionStrategy(sessionRegistry));
    delegateStrategies.add(new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry));
    return new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(delegateStrategies);
}
```

that's all I have to say about that quote :)

Answer (score -1):

Where does the sessionRegistry instance come from when instantiating

```
new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry)
```

Make sure this is the same instance as your sessionRegistry() returns (beware that calling that method multiple times will create multiple instances!)

Also, I don't see any code where the sessionAuthenticationStrategy is bound to session management:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());
}
```